Using two junction boxes for one set of light switches
I’m wiring a 5 gang light switch. The boxes are pretty crowded. Can I per code use two junction boxes in this manner?
The first junction box will be in the basement just below the switches. I will combine all my neutrals and grounds here. Emerging from this box will be 5 “pigtails” for each light switch above. The pigtails will be just x-2 NM cable. They will go directly to the junction box with switches and be connected to them straight, no additional wire nutting there.
For 3 way switches, I would put travelers in the switch boxes to continue on, although I’m not sure this is possible, as I may need to connect all of these anyway.

This might be OK. But I suspect only if you used boxes connected with a piece of conduit ("conduit nipple"). And if you do that then you would want to use metal boxes so you don't need ground wires to the switches. And you would also need to have the "extra" junction box accessible - so a blank plate over it and either in a regular wall (with the blank plate visible) or in an open accessible area (e.g., on the wall or ceiling of an unfinished area).
But multiple switches are really not a problem. All you really need is the right type of box. I would use gangable metal boxes. Basically you take off one side of one for each end and both sides of the boxes in the middle and screw them all together to make one giant box. Something like this Southwire from Home Depot:

Cables come in through clamps on the knockouts. Grounds go to the box. Other wires capped (if you have neutrals and switches that don't need neutrals) or go to the switches. Switches ground through yoke to box. Plenty of space. Done.
